# Turn off context menu for Component applied by CnPack (design time)

Tags: delphi, delphi-6

After I installed cnPack, right clicking on a component in my form seems to have taken away any specific items that the component itself may have applied.

eg, right clicking on any Dev Express component will usually bring up version details.  Now I get a bunch of other context menu items and the Dev Express ones have disappeared.

Is there a wizard or some other option I can disable to stop this?  I can't find one anywhere.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Restarting Delphi fixed it in the short term - but has come back again so I'd still like to find a resolution to this....

Comment: Try asking this question in the CNPack forums http://bbs.cnpack.org/

Comment: Yep will do.  Thanks.  I'll post the answer back here if I receive one there.

Comment: Are you try disable "Form Designer Enhancements"?

Answer (score 2):

Right-click menus are controlled by component editors, and AFAIK there can only be one component editor registered to a particular class type at a time. If CnPack's design-time package is loaded after DevExpress's design-time package, then CnPack's component editor will be the last one registered and take priority.